# How to add new value in the value already available in sql row

Tags: php, sql

I want the code to work so that when users earn an amount it should be added to the `Paid` table, e.g. after adding it should contain User amount + Earned

My Code currently adds a new row on every claim, but I want instead to update the users' balance if an `address` is already in the table.

Example: User Balance is 15.2 and they earned 2.3 this balance should be updated to 17.5

```
$address = trim($_POST["address"]);
$q = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$dbtable_prefix."Paid
                    SET
                        `address` = ?,
                        `amount` = ?
                        ;");
$claimlog_reward = $reward;
if ($reward<1) {
    $claimlog_reward = number_format($reward, 8, '.', '');
}
$
q->execute(array(trim($_POST['address']), $claimlog_reward));
```

Comment: Do `UPDATE` instead if `INSERT`. Don't forget the `WHERE` clause, otherwise all rows will be updated.

Comment: In this case you'll fail if the user has no entry in paid table

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume MySQL / MariaDB - Add a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` update (provided your address is a primary key)

```
$address = trim($_POST["address"]);
$claimlog_reward = $reward;
if ($reward<1) {
  $claimlog_reward = number_format($reward, 8, '.', '');
}

$q = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$dbtable_prefix."Paid
SET `address` = :address, `amount` = :amount
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + :amount");
$q->bindValue(':address', trim($_POST['address']));
$q->bindValue(':amount', $claimlog_reward);
$q->execute();
```

Comment: it also inserts as a new row.

Comment: That's the point. You said you did not want several rows with the same address didn't you ?